# Contradiction to the law of conservation of energy while time travelling

Tags: energy-conservation, time-travel, wormholes

If time travelling backward were possible,(by a wormhole, one opening of which has been kept near a massive body, for instance) wouldn't it contradict the law of conservation of energy, since a previously nonexistent packet of energy (the mass of the traveller) has appeared, a point of time in the past?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impossibility of time travel due to energy conservation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201031/)

Comment: Also related: [Physics errors in the movie “Arrival”](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338109//).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't explicitely contradict the conservation of energy, but create a situation where it could not apply anymore, like in a lot of system (like a disipative system).
Conservation of energy is a consequence of the invariance of a system over time (see the Noether theorem). I guess in your situation it depends how you define time (and your sistem, but I guess you consider the whole universe):

- if you make your time a straigt and unberturbed arrow, then you suddently make something disappear. Your system is not invariant with time (it is not isolated, but connected to the past) and the conservation of energy is not valid.
- if somehow you make your time as a loop going to the past (I am not sure how to do that), the energy would be conserved...